# Array.Clear(name, 0, len) not working

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a string array declared like this:

```
string[] strA9 = new string[64];
```

After using it, I want to reset all elements back to null but this code

```
Array.Clear(strA9, 0, strA9.Length);
```

only clears the first 3 elements where were previously used. So I can't access str9[5] without getting an error saying that element doesn't exist.

I thought the .Clear method would reset the array back to 64 null elements?

Comment: `Arrat.Clear` does that. You have a different problem using the array. What error do you get when you access the str9[5]- and how do you access it? Please post the relevant code so we can help

Comment: My guess is that somewhere else you're assigning a new value to `strA9` which is a reference to an array with only 5 elements. But without a [mcve] we can't really tell.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are clearing the array is correct since is the same as what is defined in the [documentation site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.array.clear(v=vs.110).aspx), (maybe there is something behind the code that you are not posting in the question).

```
string[] strA9 = { "A", "B","java" };
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", strA9));
Console.WriteLine(strA9[1]);
Array.Clear(strA9, 0, strA9.Length);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", strA9));
```

Comment: Then if so what is the problem in the question? This is an X-Y problem where OP stated something else than the real problem. Thus, I am not sure this answer helps answer the question and should be a comment

Comment: The array is declared like this:

string[] strA9 = new string[64];

It was previously used with data like this:
strA9[0] = "test1"
strA9[1] = "test2"
strA9[2] = "test3"

When I try to clear this array I see this:
strA9[0] = null
strA9[1] = null
strA9[2] = null

So I've lost my 64 size somehow. So the next time I try to use the array and access element, say 5, I get the out of bounds runtime error.

I thought the clear array would give me back all 64 array elements set to null.

Comment: I ended up using this to solve it

strA9 = new string[64];